Why are most mint accounts initialized as on-curve addresses
Is there a reason why most mint account addresses are on-curve consisting of both public and private keys.
For on-chain programs, is there a problem when the mint account is derived as a PDA?

There's no problem with a mint being a PDA, it just isn't a common use-case. In most cases, it's much easier to let people bring their own mint, so they create with a random keypair and then use it with a protocol.

I'm guessing the reason most mints are on-curve in practice is because this makes minting tokens easy, as you just need to create a normal mint_to instruction on the client side and sign it with your mint keypair without needing a special program to manage minting.
That being said, there's no problem with using a PDA and writing a program that manages mint logic of course.
